# using inherited_resource, how do you customize collections use in belongs_to relationships

Tags: ruby-on-rails, simple-form, inherited-resources

Here's what I have:

https://gist.github.com/chewmanfoo/9791992

But the collections rendered in the form are as if the controller create action had not been run.  (it renders `Environment.all`, `Role.all`).

I can't figure out how to customize those collections.  Note that the change should not affect Environment and Role permanently (I can't change Environment so that it's collection is always filtered), I have to change the `refreshes_controller`.